# How logback determines number of threads and feasible way for fast logging

Tags: java, low-latency

I am using logback with sl4j for logging with in my application. When profiling my application , I can see around 8 logback threads running ,and not doing anything -- as i have removed all logging to support low latency requirements for application.

How logback determines number of threads and how we can control it ?

To support latency  && minimum object allocation to avoid GC requirements, applciation stores all logs binary messages in Ring buffer which is read by separate thread for logging.

1. I can use log4j which have less allocation in comparison to logback, but it still allocates.
2. USe String builder of fixed length, but it will convert toString while saving in logs, which will creates objects.
3. Use empty memory map file and dump encoded messages to file, however we need to use another utility for reading logs which is not user friendly.

Is there any other solution by which I can dump String messages to pre mapped file ?

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944821/logback-thread-pool) will help, not sure it's the same thing though